# how to show jsp in response to an ajax call to a servlet

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, search, servlets

i am sending search parameters to a search servlet using ajax and that servlet is searching the database. now i am dispatching the request to  SearchResults.jsp where i am showing the results.

```
String nextJSP = "/s/SearchResults.jsp";
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

The problem is that i am getting full jsp in response to the ajax call , but i want the SearchResults.jsp page to be opened with the results after the ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use JSP for this. It's good for HTML stuff only. Just let the servlet return JSON or XML and process it in JS side. Here's a kickoff example assuming that you want to search for products and that the `Product` class has properties `name`, `description` and `price` which you'd like to show in a table.

`products.jsp`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 5336889</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#search').submit(function() {
                    $.get(this.action, $(this).serialize(), function(products) {
                        var $table = $('<table>').appendTo($('#results'));
                        $.each(products, function(index, product) {
                            var $tr = $('<tr>').appendTo($table);
                            $('<td>').text(product.name).appendTo($tr);
                            $('<td>').text(product.description).appendTo($tr);
                            $('<td>').text(product.price).appendTo($tr);
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="search" action="products">
            Search products:
            <input name="query" />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        <div id="results"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In combination with a servlet which listens on an URL pattern of `/products`:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    List<Product> products = productDAO.find(request.getParameter("query"));
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(products));
}
```

*(where `Gson` is [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/))*.

#### See also:

- [Updating page with ajax and servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/update-current-page-with-a-servlet)
- [Ajax calculator example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114742/simple-calculator-in-jsp)

Answer (score 1):

There is a similiar question: [best practice to render JSON data in JSPs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/278912/554084)
This is sample for json to return json data: http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/JSPAndAJAXExamples
Also there is some jsp tab lib like:http://json-taglib.sourceforge.net/

In short, you can control what to output in the jsp by juding the request accept type.